# Can you still access your app from iOS after your Apple Developer enrollment is expired?

Tags: ios, iphone

I submitted an app to the iOS store about 2-3 years ago.  This was back when iOS 6 was still around.  My Apple Developer account has been inactive since ($99 / year fee, bah!).  When I attempt to log into my account, I can't seem to access iTunes connect even though I was the primary developer for my apps.

I'm wondering about if it is still possible to get access my apps without paying the $99 enrollment fee again?

Might there be a repo somewhere that I can access my uploaded files I sent over to Apple?

Comment: What are you trying to access from iTunesConnect?  There isn't anything you can download- your source code etc you should still have on your computer.  Without paying your developer registration fee you don't have access to iTunesConnect.  If you do pay the fee I don't know if they will reactivate your old account with its old content or whether you will start from scratch again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is No. You can't access the applications that submitted.

Your submitted applications will disappear from the app store within a short period time after expiring your Apple developer account.

The glad news is, if you renew your membership later, you can see your apps in the App Store within 24 hours. That means, you do not want to resubmit them.

Please read the Developer.Apple section about the [program-renewals.](https://developer.apple.com/support/mac/program-renewals.php)